# Data is getting in one replica set only

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, sharding, replicaset

I have three replica set and trying to do sharding .

Even i am adding 500000 documents in a collection data is getting inside one shard only ? . This is first time i am trying to create shard.

I have also posted the output of getShardDistribution on collection abcd and mybooks

abcd collection is inside database shardingFinalDemo and mybooks is inside book.

And for each collection it is making one chunk of whole dataset

this is the output of sh.status()

```
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5e95cb79e8628e83e972957b")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "first shard",  "host" : "first shard/localhost:27011,localhost:27012,localhost:27013",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "second shard",  "host" : "second shard/localhost:27021,localhost:27022,localhost:27023",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "sharding 3 ",  "host" : "sharding 3 /localhost:27031,localhost:27032,localhost:27033",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "4.2.2" : 1
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "books",  "primary" : "second shard",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("97774c76-23f3-4455-af44-6b1f15f849c9"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                books.myBooks
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: true
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                second shard    1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : second shard Timestamp(1, 0) 
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                first shard 1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : first shard Timestamp(1, 0) 
        {  "_id" : "demoDb",  "primary" : "sharding 3 ",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("41903e6a-fcff-4ad6-8618-70b0fd5b3c07"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                demoDb.demoShard
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: true
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                sharding 3  1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : sharding 3  Timestamp(1, 0) 
        {  "_id" : "demoShard",  "primary" : "first shard",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("49913dce-d505-42cd-9009-a67f6f002b82"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
        {  "_id" : "shardingFinalDemo",  "primary" : "first shard",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("61324d20-5e3b-437d-ae52-542d479fd244"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                shardingFinalDemo.abcd
                        shard key: { "name" : 1 }
                        unique: true
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                first shard 1
                        { "name" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "name" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : first shard Timestamp(1, 0)
```

```
db.abcd.getShardDistribution()

Shard first shard at first shard/localhost:27011,localhost:27012,localhost:27013
 data : 249KiB docs : 5000 chunks : 1
 estimated data per chunk : 249KiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 5000

Totals
 data : 249KiB docs : 5000 chunks : 1
 Shard first shard contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 51B
```

```
db.myBooks.getShardDistribution()

Shard second shard at second shard/localhost:27021,localhost:27022,localhost:27023
 data : 25.16MiB docs : 455009 chunks : 1
 estimated data per chunk : 25.16MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 455009

Totals
 data : 25.16MiB docs : 455009 chunks : 1
 Shard second shard contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 58B
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have chosen _id as the shard key. This is generally going to put consecutive documents in the same shard which is what you appear to be experiencing. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#monotonically-changing-shard-keys) for an explanation.

Try:

- Using a hashed shard key of the _id field
- Using a different field as the shard key

Comment: Its also causing problem if
1.insert the records in collection  and then do sharding on it then it then creates a single chunk of dataset

But if i do sharding initially then inserting the records in it then it is working fine . It then divides the dataset into multiple chunks

So how can divide into multiple chunks even if the records are inserted before and sharding is done afterwards

Comment: Use a different shard key.